# Why after i use zoom/scale css in a div , the height/width property remains original even if the div is scaled?

Tags: html, css

it is a css spinner , but i can't center it in the page. The height/width remains 200px even if it is scaled 50%.

```html
<div class="center" style="">
  <div class="uil-default-css" style="width: 200px;height: 200px;position: absolute;left: 50%;top: 50%;zoom:0.5;-moz-transform:scale(0.5);">
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(0deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(30deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(30deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(60deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(60deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(90deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(120deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(120deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(150deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(150deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(180deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(210deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(210deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(240deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(240deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(270deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(300deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(300deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(330deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(330deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

center css is

> ```
> text-align: center;
> display: table-cell;
> vertical-align: middle;
> ```

Comment: Scaling is applied *AFTER* width/height. So the width/height doesn't actually change, it's more like you "zoom in" on an object with a camera; the object doesn't change, only what you see changes.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what u want?

I have centered it using `transform:translate(-50%,-50%);`

Also u should give `position:relative` if u are using absolute positioning,
And in your case, to actually center it, you have to provide height to the parent.

Otherwise, the spinner will not know, w.r.t what it has to center

Another option, 
if u want to use the loader as fullpage loader,

then u can use `position:fixed` and center it the same way like above, and u dont need to provide `position:relative` to parent.

```css
.uil-default-css {
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.5);
}

.center {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="center" style="">
  <div class="uil-default-css" style="width: 200px;height: 200px;position: absolute;left: 50%;top: 50%;">
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(0deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(30deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(30deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(60deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(60deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(90deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(120deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(120deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(150deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(150deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(180deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(210deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(210deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(240deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(240deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(270deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(300deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(300deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="top:80px;left:93px;width:14px;height:40px;background:#00b2ff;-webkit-transform:rotate(330deg) translate(0,-60px);transform:rotate(330deg) translate(0,-60px);border-radius:10px;position:absolute;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes , i found the error there was a js function calculating the height in wrong way . It doesn' t calculate  viewport height for parent div .

Comment: @abubiabubi if this anser helped u please accept it

Comment: I thank you for support, sorry. I just added in my case there was a problem also in the parent div.